# How to abort an http request in angularjs, when the controller which invoked the request lost its scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I created an application in angularjs in which uses ng-view. By the hep of route provider, four different modules are loaded in the ng-view.
In each module I m sending http request in the following way:-

```
var requestManager = {
    "locations": {},
    "employees": {},
    "items": {},
    "templates": {}
};
sendRequestToServer = function (reqObj) {
    var reqObj = reqObj,
        httpObj = {},
        defer = $q.defer();
    httpObj = {
        method: reqObj.method,
        url: baseUrl + reqObj.url,
        timeout: 90000
    };
    if (reqObj.method == 'GET') {
        httpObj['params'] = reqObj.data;
        if (reqObj.uniqueId) {
            httpObj['headers'] = {
                'uniqueId': uniqueId
            }
        }
    } else if (reqObj.method == 'POST' || reqObj.method == 'PUT') {
        httpObj['headers'] = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        };
        httpObj['data'] = reqObj.data;
    }
    requestManager[reqObj.moduleName][reqObj.requestName] = $http(httpObj).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        var dataObj = {
            data: data,
            status: status,
            headers: headers,
            config: config
        };
        defer.resolve(dataObj);
    })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            var dataObj = {
                data: data,
                status: status,
                headers: headers,
                config: config
            };
            defer.reject(dataObj);
        });
    return defer.promise;
}
```

Now my requirement is :- when the route change from one module to another, I want to abort the request which are in middle of the server communication.
To do that I m listening to the destroy event :-

```
$rootScope.$on('destroyModule', function(event, moduleName) {

    var requests = requestManager[moduleName]
        , defer = $q.defer()
        , index
        , req;
    for(req in requests){

    //Want abort the request
        defer.reject(requests[req]);

    }
})
```

But it is not working.. I think what i m doing is wrong. Can anybody help on this topic??
Thanks you in advance

Comment: Please please please do not reject with stuff that's not an error. ALWAYS reject with an error as it will give you stack traces.

Comment: Also, consider rewriting your code to avoid the https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern

Comment: I read the github link which you provided. But My problem how can i achieve my requirement to abort the request which i already sent..Can you help me please.

Answer (score 0):

The destroy event won't fire on the $rootScope, if you have another scope you can listen too (possibly in a views controller?) you can wire that up like this:

```
$scope.$on("$destroy", function(){ ... });
```

If on the other hand you just want to detect when location changes you can do this:

```
$rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(){ ... });
```

Comment: How can I get the track of http request which is already sent before the scope got destroyed